# DD4T DefaultCacheAgent - GetLastPublishedDateCallBack called for unexpected object type

Tags: dd4t

I am having an issue getting the DD4T DefaultCacheAgent to work. I am using Castle Windsor and have the DI setup like this.

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICacheAgent>().ImplementedBy<DefaultCacheAgent>().LifestyleTransient());
```

When setup like this it works. However, notice it is setup as "Transient". Transient seems to defeat the purpose of having a cache so I tried to make it Singleton. However, whenever I make it anything but transient I get this error:

> GetLastPublishedDateCallBack called for unexpected object type
>   'DD4T.ContentModel.Component' or with unexpected key
>   'ComponentByUri_tcm:17-1721_'

It is as though it is trying to get something from the cache that it has not put in the cache yet but does not know any better.

Here is what is in the core log and the caching log.

**Core**

> 2014-09-02 16:46:58,713 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Retrieved ComponentMeta instance: com.tridion.storage.mapper.ComponentMetaImpl@58b7d0f
>   2014-09-02 16:46:58,760 DEBUG MapperFactory - No data provided for mapping; mapping to empty custom meta
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,353 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Started Retrieving ComponentMeta instance
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,353 DEBUG MapperFactory - No data provided for mapping; mapping to empty custom meta
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,354 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Retrieved ComponentMeta instance: com.tridion.storage.mapper.ComponentMetaImpl@8bf66a1
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,619 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Started Retrieving ComponentMeta instance
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,619 DEBUG MapperFactory - No data provided for mapping; mapping to empty custom meta
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,620 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Retrieved ComponentMeta instance: com.tridion.storage.mapper.ComponentMetaImpl@4dead883
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,727 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Started Retrieving ComponentMeta instance
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,727 DEBUG MapperFactory - No data provided for mapping; mapping to empty custom meta
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,728 DEBUG ComponentMetaFactory - Retrieved ComponentMeta instance: com.tridion.storage.mapper.ComponentMetaImpl@752ca86b
>   2014-09-02 16:46:59,775 DEBUG MapperFactory - No data provided for mapping; mapping to empty custom meta

**Caching**

> 2014-09-02 16:46:51,321 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 52  memSize = 225230
>   2014-09-02 16:46:51,322 DEBUG CacheController - Adding a dependency from Object [17:1669] in Region [/com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta] to Object [17:1669:ComponentMeta:true] in Region [/com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta]
>   2014-09-02 16:46:51,445 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 53  memSize = 225828
>   2014-09-02 16:46:51,564 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 54  memSize = 226103
>   2014-09-02 16:46:51,564 DEBUG CacheController - Adding a dependency from Object [17:1646] in Region [/com_tridion_linking_ComponentLinkInfo] to Object [false:false:17:0:1646:0::] in Region [/com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink]
>   2014-09-02 16:46:51,565 DEBUG CacheController - Adding a dependency from Object [17:0] in Region [/com.tridion.broker.pages.meta.PageMeta] to Object [false:false:17:0:1646:0::] in Region [/com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink]
>   2014-09-02 16:51:36,710 INFO  CacheFactory - No policy configured, creating a cache with an empty policy.
>   2014-09-02 16:51:36,711 INFO  CacheFactory - No policy configured, creating a cache with an empty policy.
>   2014-09-02 16:53:41,975 INFO  CacheFactory - No policy configured, creating a cache with an empty policy.
>   2014-09-02 16:53:41,977 INFO  CacheFactory - No policy configured, creating a cache with an empty policy.

**DD4T log**

> 2014-09-02 16:57:16,366 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>GetComponent (tcm:17-1721)
>   2014-09-02 16:57:16,368 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>TryGetComponent (tcm:17-1721)
>   2014-09-02 16:57:16,372 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>GetContent(tcm:17-1721)
>   2014-09-02 16:57:16,376 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContent: about to find all component presentations for tcm:17-1721
>   2014-09-02 16:57:16,881 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContent: found all component presentations for tcm:17-1721
>   2014-09-02 16:57:16,891 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - <>LastPublishDateChangeMonitor(ComponentByUri_tcm:17-1721_, DD4T.ContentModel.Component)
>   2014-09-02 16:57:17,033 [5] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>GetLastPublishedDateCallBack ComponentByUri_tcm:17-1721_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with trying to reuse a single ICacheAgent instance is that both the ComponentFactory and PageFactory classes override the GetLastPublishDateCallBack property, and both make assumptions about the type of cached objects they will handle. The ComponentFactory assumes that the cached objects will implement IComponent; the PageFactory assumes the cached objects will implement IPage. When the two factories share an ICacheAgent, they end up stepping on each other. In your scenario, the cache agent for the ComponentFactory is running the callback for the PageFactory.

Because of this, the ICacheAgent registration needs to be transient. The DefaultCacheAgent stores cached objects in the default MemoryCache instance, so there's no issue with creating many new DefaultCacheAgent instances---they'll all share the same underlying cache.

An alternative would be to create a callback that can handle both IPage and IComponent instances. You would need to create custom PageFactory and ComponentFactory classes, and override the GetLastPublishDateCallBack method in both to use your new, custom callback.